# include not found copySpec / Sync task Gradle

Tags: gradle, include, synchronization, task

I'm trying to sync specific files from a dir with Gradle. But I get a odd error that I can't seem to solve. If there is a better (working) way to filter files while syncing that would also be welcome.

**Implementation 1**

```
def updateAbstractsContentSpec = copySpec {
    from('../../base') {
        includes "../../base/shared/**/*_abstract.*"
    }
}

task updateAbstracts(type: Sync) {
    group 'build'
    with updateAbstractsContentSpec
}
```

**Error 1**

```
Error:(24, 0) Could not find method includes() for arguments [../../base/shared/**/*_abstract.*] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecWrapper_Decorated.
```

**Implementation 2 (Preferable)**

```
task updateAbstracts(type: Sync) {
    group 'build'
    from '../../base'
    includes '../../base/shared/**/*_abstract.*'
}
```

**Error 2**

```
Error:(23, 0) Could not find method includes() for arguments [../../base/shared/**/*_abstract.*] on task ':apps:TestApp1:updateAbstracts' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.
```

I assume that its clear what I try to do. I hope that somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of  [Gradle 3.0 CopySpec documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html), **`CopySpec` does not contain `includes` method.**

You should use include instead:

```
task updateAbstracts(type: Sync) {
    group 'build'
    from '../../base'
    include '../../base/shared/**/*_abstract.*'
}
```